# Find expected value of continuous density distribution - integration problem

Tags: calculus

> I need to find the expected value of a random variables Y with density $$p(y;\theta)=\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1},\ \theta > 0,\ y \in(0,1)$$

Based on the definition of expected value:
$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int^1_0y\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1}dy$$

I think I can solve it with integration by parts but I'm need a hint :-)

**Edit with solution**

$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int^1_0y\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1}dy=\theta\left[-\frac{(1-y)^{\theta}}{\theta}y\ \Bigg |_0^1-\int^1_0\left(-\frac{(1-y)^{\theta}}{\theta}\right)dy\right]=\frac{1}{1+\theta}$$

**Alternative solution**

The definition of beta function is $B(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$. When $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive integer 
$B(1,\theta)=\frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}{\Gamma(1+\theta)}=\frac{(\theta-1)!}{\theta!}=\frac{1}{\theta}$.

In this case $p(y;\theta)=\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1}\sim Beta(1,\theta)$ so $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{1}{1+\theta}$

Comment: consider the beta-gamma function relationship.

Comment: *"I think I can solve it with integration by parts."* Yes, that. Have you tried?

Comment: However, I think integration by parts works just fine with $u=y$ and $(1-y)^{\theta-1}dy=dv$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Hi, I solved it $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int^1_0y\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1}dy=\theta\left[-\frac{(1-y)^{\theta}}{\theta}y\ \Bigg |_0^1-\int^1_0\left(-\frac{(1-y)^{\theta}}{\theta}\right)dy\right]=\frac{1}{1+\theta}$

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I used also the beta-gamma function relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use integration by parts, change variables $1-y=t$. You get
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int^1_0y\theta(1-y)^{\theta-1}dy=\theta\int_0^1 dt (1-t)t^{\theta-1}=\theta\left[\int_0^1 dt\ t^{\theta-1}-\int_0^1 dt\ t^{\theta}\right]\ ,
$$
and the two integrals are now elementary.